# Arduino .read() function interfering with BLE connection

Tags: c++, c, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Firstly, I want to apologize as I am new to BLE connectivity and much of Arduino programming. I am busy with a project which in involved making a smart coffee scale which can output data to a smartphone via a BLE connection. I am working with an Arduino nano 33 IoT, and an hx711 load cell amplifier.

I need to create a program where I can send and receive data to and from the Arduino to the smartphone app. I have used standard ArduinoBLE peripheral libraries such as the "BatteryMonitor" sketch and the "ButtonLED" sketch. By combining both of these example sketches together I have managed to established a connection where I can send and receive data.

The problem arises when I try to use functions within the HX711 library such as scale.read(); to retrieve values being output from the hx711 amplifier. When I use a serial read function such as scale.read() the bluetooth connection fails before establishing itself properly. I imagine this is due to the scale.read() function interfering with the serial data being transmitted and received by the Arduino, but I have no clue how to get around this problem.

I basically want to change the battery monitor output to be the output of the value read from the hx711 load cell amplifier but I am struggling to get this to work.

```
#include "HX711.h"
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

HX711 scale;

BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); // BLE LED Service

// BLE LED Switch Characteristic - custom 128-bit UUID, read and writable by central
BLEByteCharacteristic switchCharacteristic("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214", BLERead | BLEWrite);

BLEUnsignedCharCharacteristic batteryLevelChar("2A19",  // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID
    BLERead | BLENotify); // remote clients will be able to get notifications if this characteristic changes

int oldBatteryLevel = 0;  // last battery level reading from analog input
long previousMillis = 0;  // last time the battery level was checked, in ms
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN; // pin to use for the LED
 double val;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  scale.begin(A1, A0);    //Initialized scale on these pins
  while (!Serial);

  scale.set_scale(432.f);                      // this value is obtained by calibrating the scale with known weights; see the README for details
  scale.tare();               // reset the scale to 0
  

  // set LED pin to output mode
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // begin initialization
  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("starting BLE failed!");

    while (1);
  }

  // set advertised local name and service UUID:
  BLE.setLocalName("COFFEE");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(ledService);

  // add the characteristic to the service
  ledService.addCharacteristic(switchCharacteristic);
  ledService.addCharacteristic(batteryLevelChar); // add the battery level characteristic


  // add service
  BLE.addService(ledService);

  // set the initial value for the characeristic:
  switchCharacteristic.writeValue(0);

  // start advertising
  BLE.advertise();

  Serial.println("BLE LED Peripheral");
}

void loop() 
{
  // listen for BLE peripherals to connect:
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  // if a central is connected to peripheral:
  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central: ");
    // print the central's MAC address:
    Serial.println(central.address());

    // while the central is still connected to peripheral:
    while (central.connected()) 
    {
      
      // Battery Monitor 
      //  scale.read();
        long currentMillis = millis();
      // if 200ms have passed, check the battery level:
      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 200) {
         previousMillis = currentMillis;
      //  scale.read();                    // This function alone will prevent the BLE connection from establishing properly.
        updateBatteryLevel();
        
      //  outputScale();
      }
      // if the remote device wrote to the characteristic,
      // use the value to control the LED:
      if (switchCharacteristic.written()) {
        if (switchCharacteristic.value()) {   // any value other than 0
          Serial.println("LED on");
          digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);         // will turn the LED on
        } else {                              // a 0 value
          Serial.println(F("LED off"));
          digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);          // will turn the LED off
        }
      }
      
    }

    // when the central disconnects, print it out:
    Serial.print(F("Disconnected from central: "));
    Serial.println(central.address());
  }
  
  
}
void updateBatteryLevel() 
{


  /* Read the current voltage level on the A0 analog input pin.
     This is used here to simulate the charge level of a battery.
  */
  int battery = analogRead(A0);
  int batteryLevel = map(battery, 0, 1023, 0, 100);

  if (batteryLevel != oldBatteryLevel) {      // if the battery level has changed
   // Serial.print("Battery Level % is now: "); // print it
   
    Serial.println(batteryLevel);
    batteryLevelChar.writeValue(batteryLevel);  // and update the battery level characteristic
    oldBatteryLevel = batteryLevel;           // save the level for next comparison
  }
}

void outputScale(){
 int t, i, n, T;
  double val, sum, sumsq, mean;
  float stddev;
  
  n = 20;
  t = millis();
  i = sum = sumsq = 0;
  while (i<n) {
    val = ((scale.read() - scale.get_offset()) / scale.get_scale());
    sum += val;
    sumsq += val * val;
    i++;
  }
  t = millis() - t;
  mean = sum / n;
  stddev = sqrt(sumsq / n - mean * mean);
//  Serial.print("Mean, Std Dev of "); Serial.print(i); Serial.print(" readings:\t");
  Serial.print(sum / n, 3); Serial.print("\n"); // Serial.print(stddev, 3);
  // Note: 2 sigma is 95% confidence, 3 sigma is 99.7%
  //Serial.print("\nTime taken:\t"); Serial.print(float(t)/1000, 3); Serial.println("Secs\n");

  /*
  scale.power_down();             // put the ADC in sleep mode
  delay(5000);
  scale.power_up();
  */

}
```

Comment: Arduino Nano 33 IoT is SAM21 based microcontroller. They clearly mention in [GitHub](https://github.com/bogde/HX711) that it is untested. However this does not mean that it will not work. `scale.begin(A1, A0);` you initialize like this and then in `updateBatteryLevel` method there is `int battery = analogRead(A0);`. Can you elaborate this?

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't notice my mistake there. Problem solved :)

Comment: I will add this as an answer, please accept so the question will be closed.

Comment: Always read documentation, source code, and datasheet.  Using any library without doing so is "hope as a strategy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initialising as `scale.begin(A1, A0)` while trying to read from the same `A0` pin.